# Delete everything inside a tag but another tag jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of html

```
    <div id="Cart">
    <p>
        You have <strong>1</strong> item in your cart.
        Your sub total is <strong>$35.00</strong>.
    </p>
    </div>
```

I need to be able to get the information between the `<strongs>` and delete everything else, is that possible with jquery? I tried `$("#Cart strong:not()")` But didn't select anything, I thought maybe placing the info in a variable, deleting everything with .remove and reprinting the variables but I don't really know how to do that, can someone help me?.

The information between the strong is dynamic, I believe all the other is in a php file that I dont have access to... maybe filtering the words and removing them? Any advice will be welcome :)

Comment: im not sure what you mean. you want to select the text that says "You have item in your cart. Your sub total is." ?

Comment: no that text I need to remove... then print something like "data from first strong" items total: "data from second strong"

Comment: You're probably better off wrapping what you want in a `<div id="someID">`. As in: You have `<div id="itemCount"><strong>1</strong></div>` items in your cart.

Comment: You can create a container `var container = $("<div>");`, then move all `<strong>` elements from the tree: `$("#Cart strong").appendTo(p);`, then wipe the contents of the cart, and append the `<strong>` tags: `$("#Cart").html("").append(container.children());`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some code to get you started:

```
var strongs = [];
$('#Cart strong').each(function() {
    strongs.push($(this).text());
});
$('#Cart').html('First strong contains: ' + strongs[0] + '; And the second: ' + strongs[1]);
```

Here's an example of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/SBRhk/

Comment: Exactly what I need it Thank you very much!

Comment: Just I fast question, what is .push for?  and do you recommend me any good jquery book? :) (I only find .pushStack() in the jquery docs :( )

Comment: `push` is a (native) Javascript function which adds an element to an array. So `[].push(3)` will result in `[3]`. I don't think you need more than the documentation for using jQuery (it's not a big library), just be sure to learn and understand Javascript. I don't want to advertise here for books, but there are lots of good ones (and not that big either).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#Cart p').contents(':not(strong)').remove();
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/eboxuh/edit#javascript,html,live)

Answer (score 0):

OK so if I understand what you want, you want to get the information from the strongs.

if you are not averse to adding classes or ids to your strongs (I use id here), that is the best way.

so change ur html to:

```
<div id="Cart">
    <p>
        You have <strong id="numItems">1</strong> item in your cart.
        Your sub total is <strong id="cost">$35.00</strong>.
    </p>
</div>
```

and this is how you would get this in a string, which you can append or something where you need:

```
var yourString = "You have " + $('#Cart #numitems').text() + " item(s) in your cart. Your subtotal is: " + $('#Cart #cost').text();
```

Comment: The OP said that the info inside 'strong' is dynamic... So I'm not shure if he's able to add `id` to the `strong` itself

Comment: I cant add classes or edit that html >_<, maybe using eq:? You gave me Ideas! thx